# How do I move the launcher to another screen?

Tags: launcher, multiple-monitors

I have physically swapped the my two screens around and have used the display setting to switch them so that the mouse moves between the two screens in the expected way.

But now the launcher is attached to the screen on the right, so how can I move it to the left screen?